# jQWidgets jqxTree drag and drop fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jqwidget

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJLxF/2/) that shows my problem.
When you open "Folder A" and "Folder B", drag "Item of B" out of the folder and drag "Item of A" into "Folder B", you can't drag "Item of B" correctly anymore.

I delete the children of collapsed folders because of the performance. There are often more then 300 Items, which makes the tree very slow.

In my real program I also receive an error message: "TypeError: item is null" in the first line of the dragEnd callback function. Here is the function:

```
function( item, dropItem, args, pos ){
    var item_data = tree_map[ item.id ];
    // here i do some stuff...
    // only dropItem exists in the arguments
    return false;
};
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In my more [minimalistic test](http://jsfiddle.net/LmYHz/) I found out, that this is a bug and I got it confirmed by the jQWidgets support.

```
$("#delsel").click(function(){
    $("#jqxTree").jqxTree("removeItem", $("#jqxTree").jqxTree("getSelectedItem") );
});
```

It fails, when you delete an item. Seems to be a bug in the internal collection.